# How to prove that the feasible region is bounded?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

$$min\;x_1+x_2$$
$$s.t.\;h_1(x):=-(x_1-1)^3+x_2\le0$$
$$h_2(x):=\frac{1}{2}x_1+x_2-2\le0$$
$$h_3(x):=-x_2\le0$$

From the graph, I can deduce that the feasible region is closed and bounded considering that each of the 3 inequality constraints are $\le0$. However, how do I go about proving that the region is bounded if I cannot rely on drawing the graph?

[image]

Comment: For closedness, you can argue that each constraint defines a closed set and that the whole constraint is the intersection of these (closed) sets.

Comment: Depends on the application here, but if I were refereeing a journal article, I would take a graph as a sufficient proof of compactness tbh (given that it's only 3 constraints in $\mathbb{R}^2$). For a class, I would try to use a proof by contradiction -- suppoose you have an unbounded sequence which satisfies all 3 constraints, then pray that you can cleverly arrive at a contradiction

Comment: @kostaslampanelli closedness is easy indeed, but the question was about boundedness.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a computer-based proof done with Mathematica 13.1.

```
Exists[c, c > 0,  ForAll[{x1, x2}, -x2 <= 0 && 
1/2*x1 + x2 - 2 <= 0 && -(x1 - 1)^3 + x2^2 <= 0, 
RealAbs[x1] <= c && RealAbs[x2] <= c]];
Resolve[%,Reals]
```

> `True`

Comment: One can estimate  a bound by `ForAll[{x1, x2}, -x2 <= 0 && 
   1/2*x1 + x2 - 2 <= 0 && -(x1 - 1)^3 + x2^2 <= 0, 
  RealAbs[x1] <= c && RealAbs[x2] <= c];
Resolve[%, Reals]` which results in $c \ge 4$.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd condition is $x_2\ge0,$

the 2nd one then implies $x_1\le4,$

the 1st one then implies $x_2\le3^3$ and $x_1\ge1.$

Comment: Why is $x_1$ bounded from below?

Comment: @user64494 is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

You can try proving as follows:
if the region is unbounded then the constraints become feasible either as $x_1 \rightarrow \infty \text{or} -\infty$ or $x_2 \rightarrow \infty \text{or} -\infty$.
Now first assume $x_1 \rightarrow \infty$ and $x_2$ finite then condition 1 and condition 2 contradict each other as $h_1(x_1,x_2) \rightarrow -\infty$ and $h_2(x_1,x_2) \rightarrow \infty$. Try the other 3 cases to prove ur statement.

Comment: Think of $x_1 \to -\infty$.

Comment: Then $h_1(x_1) \rightarrow \infty$ if $x_2$ is finite.